# The DELETE method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD

Tags: laravel

My code is:

settings.blade.php (blade):

```
<form method="POST" action="{{route('user.settings', $apartment->apartment_id)}}">
    @method('delete')
    @csrf
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">Delete</button>
    </form>
```

UserController.php:

```
public function delete(Apartment $apartment)
    {
    $apartment->delete();

    return redirect()->route('dashboards.users.index')
            ->withSuccess(__('Deleted successfully'));
    }
```

web.php:

```
//Authorization based on user role

Route::group(['prefix'=>'user', 'middleware'=>['isUser','auth','PreventBackHistory']], function(){
    Route::get('dashboard',[UserController::class,'index'])->name('user.dashboard');
    Route::delete('settings/{apartment}',[UserController::class,'delete'])->name('settings.delete');
    Route::resource('settings','UserController@delete')->name('user.settings');
    Route::get('profile',[UserController::class,'profile'])->name('user.profile');
    Route::get('settings',[UserController::class,'settings'])->name('user.settings');

});
```

Could someone please help?

Comment: You are using `Route::resource` instead of `Route::delete`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Route::resource('settings','UserController@delete')->name('user.settings');
```

You are re-routing the settings again using resource. Rename 'resource' to 'get'

```
Route::get('settings','UserController@delete')->name('user.settings');
```

Keep the same route and form.

```php
Route::delete('settings/{apartment}',[UserController::class,'delete'])->name('settings.delete');
```

```php
<form method="POST" action="{{route('settings.delete', $apartment->apartment_id)}}">
    @method('delete')
    @csrf
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">Delete</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use route model binding

```
Route::delete('settings/{apartment}',[UserController::class,'delete'])->name('settings.delete');
```

Then

```
<form method="POST" action="{{route('settings.delete', $apartment->apartment_id)}}">
    @method('delete')
    @csrf
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">Delete</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not helping and now I am getting different error: "Route [settings.delete] not defined."

Comment: No, I used it. My route looks as following:     Route::delete('settings/{apartment}',[UserController::class,'delete'])->name('settings.delete');

Comment: Users related routes:    GET|HEAD  user/dashboard ..................................................... user.dashboard › UserController@index
  GET|HEAD  user/profile ....................................................... user.profile › UserController@profile
  GET|HEAD  user/settings .................................................... user.settings › UserController@settings

Comment: It is not on the list

Comment: I definitely have issue with routes. After doing that I have error:   Too few arguments to function Illuminate\Routing\PendingResourceRegistration::name(), 1 passed in D:\xampp2\htdocs\sofija\routes\web.php on line 57 and exactly 2 expected

Comment: Here it is https://codefile.io/f/QToH8kR8gJzDaqSxBGbu

Comment: For your knowledge right implementation is `Route::resource('settings',UserController::class)`. See [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/controllers#resource-controllers)

Comment: I deleted this row and it helped and now if I run the list of routes I can see  DELETE    user/settings/{apartment} ........................................ settings.delete › UserController@delete on the list. But I am still getting the error Route [user.settings.delete] not defined.

Comment: I was able to delete the record. That you!

Comment: I did. It says my feedback has been recorded